# Chartboost always crashes in iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, chartboost

Here is code:

```
Chartboost *cb = [Chartboost sharedChartboost];
cb.delegate = self;
cb.appId = CHARTBOOST_APPID;
cb.appSignature = CHARTBOOST_APPSIGNATURE;

[cb startSession];
[cb cacheInterstitial];
```

This works fine in iOS6 device but crashes in iOS5.

Crash Log:

> NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFDictionary
>   setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x1234sva8

How can I solve this problem? Already I made AdSupport.framework optional.

Comment: Which Xcode version, which SDK and which deployment target do you use?

Comment: Xcode 4.6.1, deployment iOS 4.3, Chartboost SDK 3.2.1 and tried 3.2 also..both crashes

Comment: Do you need iOS 4.3 compatibility? Compiling with deployment target iOS 5 (and iOS 6 SDK, using clang) should also solve the problem.

Comment: I dont need iOS 4.3, not getting what clang..please tell me how to use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Chartboost, but the error message indicates that the code makes use
of the modern "NSDictionary and NSArray subscripting" feature, e.g.

```
dict[@"key"] // instead of [dict objectForKey:@"key"]
```

According to the ["Objective-C Feature Availability Index"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/),
NSDictionary and NSArray subscripting requires the iOS 6.0 or later SDK and the LLVM Compiler 4.0. It deploys to  iOS 5 and later.

So if you don't need the iOS 4.3 compatibility, setting the deployment target to iOS 5
and compiling against the iOS 6 SDK should solve the problem. Make sure that "Apple LLVM compiler" and not "LLVM GCC" or similar
is set as compiler in the build settings.

Answer (score 1):

Crash Fixed!

I followed solution in this post: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3893/chartboost-ios-binding-works-on-ios-6-but-crashes-on-ios-5

Just I added  lib arclite.a to my project and fixed crash.